# conditionally rename variables with dplyr rename_*

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I want to conditionally rename variables by adding a prefix before all variables names that begin with a number. When I try to do so using rename_* functions I encounter errors.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ds <- 
  tibble(
    `4 grade` = c(1,2,3),
    `6 grade` = c(1,2,3),
    `G8 grade` = c(1,2,3),
  )

ds

# my function works with rename_all
ds %>% rename_all( ~ paste0("G", .) )

# but when I try to apply my function conditionally I get an error
ds %>% rename_at( vars(starts_with("[[:digit:]]")), ~paste0("G", .) )
ds %>% rename_at( vars(str_detect("^[[:digit:]]")), ~paste0("G", .) )
ds %>% rename_if( str_detect("^[[:digit:]]"), ~paste0("G", .) )
```

How can I use conditional logic with rename_* to specify which variables to rename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `tidyselect` helper function called `matches` that enables regex search on variable names. Note that `starts_with` doesn't work because it only accepts string literals:

```
library(dplyr)

ds %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("^[0-9]")), ~ paste0("G", .))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  `G4 grade` `G6 grade` `G8 grade`
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1          1          1          1
2          2          2          2
3          3          3          3
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility could be:

```
ds %>%
 rename_at(grep("^[0-9]", names(.), value = TRUE), list(~ paste0("G", .)))

  `G4 grade` `G6 grade` `G8 grade`
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1          1          1          1
2          2          2          2
3          3          3          3
```

Answer (score 2):

A possibility(reassign names).  As suggested by @IceCreamToucan we don't actually need to capture the second group hence no need for the `\\2` part in the original regex. :

```
  names(ds) <- ds %>% 
   names() %>% 
  str_replace_all(.,"(^[0-9])(\\s+)","G\\1") 
 ds
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  `G4 grade` `G6 grade` `G8 grade`
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1          1          1          1
2          2          2          2
3          3          3          3
```

Also as suggested by @IceCreamToucan we can use this with `rename_all` to remain in the same logic as OP.

```
ds %>% 
rename_all(str_replace_all, "(^[0-9])", "G\\1")
```